# How to create dummy (fake) file and folder with batch .bat or .cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Several Times, I have tried to find easy and simple way to generate some files and folders with different size for testing purpose. Although there are many complex way on the google or other place that use VBScript or Perl, but I want a simple one (.bat or .cmd files) that can be run easly on the windows 7 or 8.1 and generate some dummy files and folders...

Comment: Is there a question or do you just want to present your code? Please don't answer question noone asked.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for people to get questions to their answers, not share code. If you wanted to share your code like this, you should have made the question "how can I generate empty files and folders" and then put your code in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy all the code bellow and paste and save it as "dummyFileFolder.bat" file.

```
@echo off
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem     Fill the current directory out with some dummy files & folders 
rem
rem     Usage: dummyFileFolder.bat [folderNumber] [fileNumber]
rem
rem             [folderNumber]  define number of folder will be 
rem                             create (default=10)
rem 
rem             [fileNumber]    define number of files will be create 
rem                             inside each folder (default=5)
rem
rem             for example: dummyFileFolder.bat 2 5
rem             Fill current directory with 2 folders which have
rem             5 files inside each them.
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set folderNo=%1
set fileNo=%2

IF NOT DEFINED folderNo set folderNo=10
IF NOT DEFINED fileNo set fileNo=5

echo.
echo   Creation of %folderNo% folder(s) and %fileNo% file(s) started...
echo.
echo   Plese Wait...
echo.
echo.
echo.

for /l %%i in (1,1,%folderNo%) do call :myTask %fileNo%

echo.
echo **********************************************
echo.
echo   Task Finished Successfuly.
echo.
echo **********************************************
echo.
pause


:myTask
set fileNo=%1
set folderName=%random%
md %folderName%
for /l %%i in (1,1,%fileNo%) do dir /q /s > %~dp0%folderName%\!random!.txt
GOTO :eof
```